# __str__ method showing None value for a class local variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having an issue where a class variable is set correctly and displayed correctly inside `__init__()` when using print, however, trying to display that same variable inside the `__str__` method displays None. Three other variables generated the exact same way do not exhibit this behavior.

Here is my code:

```
class RestRequest(urllib2.Request):
    def __init__(self, host, path, data=""):
        self.host    = host
        self.data    = data
        self.path    = path

        print "RestRequest::init() path: %s" % self.path
        print "RestRequest::init() data: %s" % self.data
        print "RestRequest::init() host: %s" % self.host

        urllib2.Request.__init__(self, self.path)


    def __str__(self):
        return "RestRequest::__str__() host='%s', path='%s', data='%s'" % (self.host, self.path, self.data)
```

The print statements inside `__init__()` display the correct values. The value of host inside `__str__` is None. The path, method and data variables display correctly inside `__str__`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into a naming clash with [attributes on the super class](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/37ebb0d44808/Lib/urllib2.py#l206).  You'll need to change the names of your attributes -- or set them after `urllib2.Request.__init__` (assuming your values are compatible with what the superclass wants).

Answer (score 1):

`urllib2.Request` sets `self.host = None` in `__init__`. To prevent unexpected things happening, call the superclass `__init__` earlier in the subclass `__init__`:

```
class RestRequest(urllib2.Request):
    def __init__(self, host, path, data=""):
        urllib2.Request.__init__(self, path) # sets self.host = None
        self.host = host # resets to correct value
        self.path = path
        self.data = data
```

Comment: Since urllib2 is an old style class, I can't use super in this case can I?

Comment: @BenH ah; no, sorry, fixing.